# Rails, Devise, Postmark Gem - using postmark templates for devise mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, postmark

I'm trying to figure out how to setup my Rails 4 app so that the devise mailer sends through Postmark, using Postmark Templates.

I have postmark-rails gem in my gem file.

I have everything working, except I can't figure out how to give the confirmation token to postmark.

In Postmark I have this template:

```
To get started, please confirm your account below:

action_url_Value
```

I can't figure out how to put the following line into the template instead of action url value:

```
<%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %></div>
```

I have added the following to my initializer/devise.rb:

```
config.mailer = 'PostmarkDeviseMailer'
```

In postmark_devise_mailer.rb, I have:

```
class PostmarkDeviseMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

  def message
    mail(
      :subject => 'Hello from Postmark',
      :to  => 'sender@address.com',
      :from => 'sender@address.comm',
      :html_body => '<strong>Hello</strong> dear Postmark user.',
      :track_opens => 'true')
  end
end


  default from: "sender@address.com"

  def confirmation_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions)
  end

  def reset_password_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions)
  end

  def unlock_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :unlock_instructions)
  end
```

The next steps are less clear to me. Has anyone figured out how to use Postmark Templates as the mailer for devise transaction emails?

Answer (score 6):

The first thing you need to do is create a custom mailer in `app/mailers` in this example it is `user_mailer.rb` If you are reading this answer, I am assuming you both have a postmark account if not grab one here: [Postmark Registration](https://account.postmarkapp.com/sign_up) and I am assuming you have a template and layout selected.

One important item to remember is to make sure you assign an alias to your template. This can be found in a small link found above the template title in small gray text.

The items within `self.template_model` are 100% customizable and are shown in your layout / template editors as so: `{{product_name}}`.

```
class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer
  include PostmarkRails::TemplatedMailerMixin

  helper :application
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers

  default from: 'from_you@something.com'
  default reply_to: 'support@hammer-lane-industries.com' # Optional 

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    @admin = record
    @token = token
    # this will pass the data via the postmark-api to your template / layout these fields are 100% customizable and can be cahnged in your template / layout
    self.template_model = { product_name: 'your product',
                            username: @user.username,
                            email: @user.email,
                            confirmation_url: user_confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token, subdomain: 'add subdomain here if needed'),
                            login_url: login_root_url(subdomain: 'add subdomain here if needed'),
                            trial_length: '14-days',
                            sender_name: 'What ever you want',
                            action_url: user_confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token, subdomain: 'add subdomain here if needed'),
                            parent_company_name: 'Your company name',
                            company_address: 'Your address'}
    mail to: @admin.email, postmark_template_alias: 'devise_user_confirmation'
  end
end
```

Rinse and repeat with unlocks and password mailers, all you will need to know is the urls that you'll be sending the tokens to.

**To finish it all off:**

You will need to add a small block to your devise resource model, in this example I've used `user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :timeoutable, :trackable

  def devise_mailer
    UserMailer # Must match your mailer class
  end
end
```

Once this is done, restart your rails server, and give it a go!

I hope this helps you with hooking Postmark Templates (API) into [Devise mailers](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise)

Comment: Rather than altering the user model, you can change the devise config: `config.mailer = 'UserMailer'`

Answer (score 3):

Response from Postmark help desk is:
Unfortunately, Postmark templates don’t fit nicely into the traditional Rails ecosystem. See my reply here for more details:

https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-rails/issues/53

To sum it up, by using the Postmark API with Postmark templates you could potentially replace ActionMailer, but mixing them together presents a significant challenge. Unfortunately, we’ve never tried the "ActionMailer-free" approach with Devise, so I can’t help you here. Unless you have a good reason not to, I’d suggest going with ActionMailer templates and using the postmark-rails gem as a delivery adapter. This approach is known to work well with Devise. Please let me know if you have any questions.